# How to get http request from curl?

Tags: http, curl

I've got a curl request which looks like:

```
curl -s http://someurl1.com -H 'Accept: application/json' -u 'emv:LgKrAVkFf2c6mr4DFBQUdjBK' -d grant_type='password' -d scope='offline_access' -d username='datafiles@random.com' -d password='456Qwer()' -d acr_values='tenant:sdfdfsdf-e5e7-42d5-9881-sdfsdf' | python -m json.tool
```

How can I construct a simple HTTP request from it? I've tried to import it with postman but got `Error while importing Curl: Zero or Multiple option-less arguments. Only one is supported (the URL)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
curl http://someurl1.com -H 'Accept: application/json' -u 'emv:LgKrAVkFf2c6mr4DFBQUdjBK' -d grant_type='password' -d scope='offline_access' -d username='datafiles@random.com' -d password='456Qwer()' -d acr_values='tenant:sdfdfsdf-e5e7-42d5-9881-sdfsdf'
```

this string can be imported by Postman.